# Spam Bugs in analytics

Tags: debugging, analytics

I am getting 100 sessions on /error page on my all of three website. As it is coming from **"not set"** so unable to check the path of that traffic.

Is there any spam or how can I add any kind of filter when I don't have idea where the sessions are coming.

Please help.

**error in analytics**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the bot filtering enabled in your view? We find that it is not perfect but it's a good start.
2. Perhaps you can look at these request and see there is a set pattern; we have seen spam traffic coming from OS = Linux when typically our site visitors are mostly windows and mac. We know those are spams for sure; these requests are from weird, probably automatically generated screen size. Check city / province / OS  etc of these sessions to see if there is a set pattern.
3. Do you have a view specific for reporting? If not, it will be a good practice to create a filtered view so that you can apply these filtering logics as needed. The idea is to keep an unfiltered view for diagnosis, and a filtered view for analysis and reporting. In the new view, you can create exclude filters to block the patterns. Make sure your filter is specific enough so that it won't block more than it should.
4. Check if your site has any soft or hard redirect for those pages; it could be why the error page does not capture any additional information. (It happens a lot for 404 redirects)

Comment: Hello Lyrist,

1. I have already filtered the bot. 
2.Yes, most of the traffic coming from mac and windows, traffic source is Linux. so now what's the solution of that?
3.Yes, have a specific view for reporting where I have set many filters like my work ip, location based etc. 
4.My site has both redirection 404 soft & hard but it all are rightly pointed. 
Here we assume that many of our products has been deactivated from eCommerce websites, so may be users landing on that /error but here again It's seems wrong assumption when we you see equally sessions count on all domains.